# kamailio TM module to add delay in sending 100 Trying

Tags: kamailio

Can auto_inv_100 parameter present in kamailio TM module be triggered with a time delay. Currently it's triggered immediately once INVITE reaches kamailio module.

Answer (score 0):

The 100 is sent from inside `t_relay()` automatically if that parameter is enabled (and it is by default), and there is no delay mechanism.

What do you want to achieve?

If your objective is to send a 100 Trying only when you decide, then you can disable auto_inv_100 and use something like `sl_send_reply("100", "Trying");` where you need it, as suggested [here](https://lists.kamailio.org/pipermail/sr-users/2013-May/078005.html) by Daniel Mierla.